# Resolve type based on knowing parts seperatly

Tags: reflection, unity-container, ioc-container

Anybody know a way to resolve an object out of an IOC container, particularly Unity 2.0, when you know the class and its generic seperatly?

Simple example

```
public class DoSomeWork {bla}
public class Execute1<DoSomeWork> : IExecute {bla}
public class Execute2<DoSomeWork> : IExecute {bla}
```

A method

```
public void go(DoSomeWork k) 
{

   unityContainer.ResolveAll(IExecute<DoSomeWork>????)
}
```

inside of the container is `Execute1<DoSomeWork>:IExecute` and `Execute2<DoSomeWork>:IExecute`

Based on DoSomeWork i need to resolve all the `Execute<DoSomeWork>` classes.

Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method to create a type based on a generic type with a specific type argument:

```
public interface IExecute<T> { }

...

Type targetType = ...;
Type specificType = typeof(IExecute<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
```

Then use this type to ask the IOC for the specific instance.